# Consume WCF REST in C# throws error when using List<>

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, typeof

I'm trying to consume `WCF REST` services in `C#`. When i'm using, if the method returns array and if i type convert the code works fine. But when i tried to return as a `List<>` and when i tried to type convert its throwing me error.

//Client Code(Using Array):

```
try
            {
                string ServiceUrl = "http://localhost:58092/Service1.svc/DataService/LoadAllDatas";
                WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(ServiceUrl);
                WebResponse wres = wreq.GetResponse();

                DataContractSerializer coll = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataServiceProxy.Product[]));


                var arrProd = coll.ReadObject(wres.GetResponseStream());

                DataServiceProxy.Product[] prd = arrProd as DataServiceProxy.Product[];
                lstProd = new List<DataServiceProxy.Product>(prd);
            }
 catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

//WCF Interface Code:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IDataService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,UriTemplate="LoadAllData")]
        IList<Product> LoadAllData();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "LoadAllDatas")]
        Product[] LoadAllDatas();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "LoadAllColumnData/{Id}")]
        IList<GdColumns> LoadAllColumnData(string Id);
    }
```

When i'm trying with List with the same WCF Service,

//Client Code:

```
 try
            {
                string Service = "http://localhost:58092/Service1.svc/DataService/LoadAllData";
                WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(Service);
                WebResponse wres = wreq.GetResponse();

                DataContractSerializer coll = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataServiceProxy.IList<Product>));


                var arrProd = coll.ReadObject(wres.GetResponseStream());

               }
```

The above code throws error in the (`typeof(DataServiceProxy.List<Product>)`) part.

Error:

```
"The type or namespace 'List' does not exist in the namespace 'Web.DataServiceProxy'(are you missing an assembly reference?)"
```

I have tried changing the IList<> to List<> and return type of the service from array to list by `Configure Service Reference` still no hopes.

How can i handle this? Where i'm wrong?

Comment: The list type isn't in DataServiceProxy, remove that qualifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have made the code worked. The change should be made in the object of type and the return type in WCF. Like this,

//Code:

```
  string Service = "http://localhost:58092/Service1.svc/DataService/LoadAllData";
                WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(Service);
                WebResponse wres = wreq.GetResponse();

                DataContractSerializer coll = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(IList<DataServiceProxy.Product>));
                //   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(coll.));

                var arrProd = coll.ReadObject(wres.GetResponseStream());

                DataServiceProxy.Product[] prd = arrProd as DataServiceProxy.Product[];
                lstProd = new List<DataServiceProxy.Product>(prd);
```

//WCF:

```
   [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "LoadAllData")]
    IList<Product> LoadAllData();
```